# how to add multiple line html tages in template instead of using templateUrl in component of Angular 6?

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular6

[working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3xxL.png)
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BeP3.png)

how to solve this issue in **TS test.component.ts** in **angular 6**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use back tick(``) instead of single quote for declaring multi line string in typescript.

```
var t=`<div>
    <p>Multiline Tag test</p>
    </div>`;

 console.log(t);
```